# Python plotting issue

Tags: python, plot, figure

I wrote the following code:

```
full_list = [0, 10**3, 10**6, 10**9, 10**12, 10**15]

list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

for hash_power in full_list:
    x1 = Calc1()
    list1.append(x1)

    x2 = Calc2()
    list2.append(x2)

    x3 = Calc3()
    list3.append(x3)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(full_list,list1,'r-->',full_list,list2,'g--o',full_list,list3,'b--o')
plt.show()
```

When the figure is generated, the distribution on the x-axis only produces the first and last point, ignoring all the points from the full_list in the middle.

I know the range is really big but is there a way to display it?

Comment: what library do you use for `plt`?

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: What's the output for Calc1/2/3?

Comment: Calc returns the value (hash_power * 12.5* (24*60*60.0) / (678760110082*2**32))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have large numeric values populating your axes - you might want to consider rescaling your figure axes such that they are logarithmic instead of linear. Steps on how to do that is found in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773814/plot-logarithmic-axes-with-matplotlib-in-python).

Or even more simply, customizing the scale on your figure axes in non-logarithmic increments, which is found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451395/customize-x-axis-in-matplotlib).

Comment: Yes it worked this way

N = len(full_list)
n = np.arange(N)

Then i replaced each full_list with n